# Date Format in XML File

Tags: xml, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I need to know how can I write the formaatted date value in XML file like the one defined below :

```
 <dateNum>2006-06-01</dateNum>
```

But what I am getting as below :

```
<dateNum>2006-06-01T00:00:00+05:30</dateNum>
```

I did the following in code :

```
 operation.setDateNum(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/06/2006"));
```

And in .xsd File :

```
 <xs:element name="dateNum" type="xs:date"/>
```

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String xsdDate = operation.setDateNum(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()).split("T")[0];
```

But, in this case you must store it as string before sending it to XSD.

Below is the more recommended way of handling it.

For XSD handle of the datatype Date, take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp

Also visit http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/03/how_do_i_map_xs.html

Comment: Why would "yyyy-MM-dd" include "T" and beyond? Also note that `parse` is called on `SimpleDateFormat` to *return* a Date object, not a String. So the "T" and beyond is added by *that* consumer.

Comment: The question is more clearer now, earlier I thought you are storing it as string before sending to xml, so I was splitting it based on the char 'T' and giving you the string before it.

Comment: Thanks AurA, but as per this site http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp , the xs:date gives format as "YYYY-MM-DD", but this is not happening when you do the code. MAybe You can try

Comment: If timezone values are specified they are appended, check this http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77041.html